Data Recovery from RAID 1 - Impossible to mount disk
I have an Nvidia DGXA100 station that I use for my research. It has started to shut down brutally (just a couple minutes after startup), probably a watercooling pump breaking down (that would be the second time in as many years). In any case, I'm on a deadline and I have important experimental data on it, and not enough time to extract all of it a couple 10s/100s of MBs at a time (before it shuts down and I wait ~1h for it to cool down naturally) -- we're talking maybe 100GB of data that I would like to transfer, total.
So I have recovered the drives to try to extract the data from my laptop. The disks are supposed to be in RAID 1, I think it's hardware RAID but I'm not 100% sure. The station's OS is a fork of Ubuntu called DGXOS.  Fiddling around with the drives, I felt stumped trying to extract the data, and so I reach out to you. No partitions are detected in /dev, only /dev/sda
If I try sudo mount /dev/sda /mnt, I get
mount: /mnt: can't read superblock on /dev/sda.
       dmesg(1) may have more information after failed mount system call.

Using fdisk -l of df, the drive is not detected. testdisk does not detect the drive either. lsblk only outputs
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
sda           8:0    0     0B  0 disk 

Looking around this site some people adviced trying sudo mdadm --examine /dev/sda, which yields mdadm: No md superblock detected on /dev/sda.
I tried looking through dmesg | grep sda, which yielded
sudo dmesg | grep sda
[160532.911871] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 30515200 512-byte logical blocks: (15.6 GB/14.6 GiB)
[160532.912828] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[160532.912838] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[160532.913729] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[160532.923731]  sda: sda1
[160532.923883] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI removable disk
[160533.329382] FAT-fs (sda1): Volume was not properly unmounted. Some data may be corrupt. Please run fsck.
[162600.133163] sda: detected capacity change from 30515200 to 0
[331437.482830] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Unit Not Ready
[331437.482842] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[331437.482849] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] ASC=0x44 <<vendor>>ASCQ=0x81 
[331437.483450] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Read Capacity(16) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[331437.483454] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[331437.483457] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] ASC=0x44 <<vendor>>ASCQ=0x81 
[331437.484134] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[331437.484138] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[331437.484142] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] ASC=0x44 <<vendor>>ASCQ=0x81 
[331437.484302] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 0 512-byte logical blocks: (0 B/0 B)
[331437.484305] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 0-byte physical blocks
[331437.484940] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Test WP failed, assume Write Enabled
[331437.485154] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Asking for cache data failed
[331437.485161] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
[331437.485659] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Preferred minimum I/O size 4096 bytes not a multiple of physical block size (0 bytes)
[331437.485662] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Optimal transfer size 33553920 bytes not a multiple of physical block size (0 bytes)
[331437.486262] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
[331519.863944] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Unit Not Ready
[331519.863953] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[331519.863962] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] ASC=0x44 <<vendor>>ASCQ=0x81 
[331519.864568] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Read Capacity(16) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[331519.864574] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[331519.864579] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] ASC=0x44 <<vendor>>ASCQ=0x81 
[331519.865310] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[331519.865314] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[331519.865318] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] ASC=0x44 <<vendor>>ASCQ=0x81 
[331519.865495] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 0 512-byte logical blocks: (0 B/0 B)
[331519.865499] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 0-byte physical blocks
[331519.866028] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Test WP failed, assume Write Enabled
[331519.866204] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Asking for cache data failed
[331519.866206] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
[331519.866728] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Preferred minimum I/O size 4096 bytes not a multiple of physical block size (0 bytes)
[331519.866731] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Optimal transfer size 33553920 bytes not a multiple of physical block size (0 bytes)
[331519.867278] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
[331991.085995] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Unit Not Ready
[331991.085999] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[331991.086003] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] ASC=0x44 <<vendor>>ASCQ=0x81 
[331991.086291] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Read Capacity(16) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[331991.086294] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[331991.086296] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] ASC=0x44 <<vendor>>ASCQ=0x81 
[331991.086661] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[331991.086664] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[331991.086666] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] ASC=0x44 <<vendor>>ASCQ=0x81 
[331991.086755] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 0 512-byte logical blocks: (0 B/0 B)
[331991.086757] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 0-byte physical blocks
[331991.087041] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Test WP failed, assume Write Enabled
[331991.087128] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Asking for cache data failed
[331991.087130] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
[331991.087414] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Preferred minimum I/O size 4096 bytes not a multiple of physical block size (0 bytes)
[331991.087417] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Optimal transfer size 33553920 bytes not a multiple of physical block size (0 bytes)
[331991.088014] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
                sda: rw=4096, sector=2, nr_sectors = 2 limit=0
[332162.048953] EXT4-fs (sda): unable to read superblock
[332816.960674] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Unit Not Ready
[332816.960690] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[332816.960700] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] ASC=0x44 <<vendor>>ASCQ=0x81 
[332816.961241] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Read Capacity(16) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[332816.961255] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[332816.961264] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] ASC=0x44 <<vendor>>ASCQ=0x81 
[332816.961945] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[332816.961955] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[332816.961960] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] ASC=0x44 <<vendor>>ASCQ=0x81 
[332823.835766] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Unit Not Ready
[332823.835783] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[332823.835792] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] ASC=0x44 <<vendor>>ASCQ=0x81 
[332823.836349] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Read Capacity(16) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[332823.836359] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[332823.836365] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] ASC=0x44 <<vendor>>ASCQ=0x81 
[332823.836892] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[332823.836896] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[332823.836899] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] ASC=0x44 <<vendor>>ASCQ=0x81 
[332930.787061] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Unit Not Ready
[332930.787077] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[332930.787086] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] ASC=0x44 <<vendor>>ASCQ=0x81 
[332930.788060] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Read Capacity(16) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[332930.788071] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[332930.788077] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] ASC=0x44 <<vendor>>ASCQ=0x81 
[332930.788932] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[332930.788937] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[332930.788942] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] ASC=0x44 <<vendor>>ASCQ=0x81 
[332930.789163] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 0 512-byte logical blocks: (0 B/0 B)
[332930.789166] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 0-byte physical blocks
[332930.789758] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Test WP failed, assume Write Enabled
[332930.789955] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Asking for cache data failed
[332930.789959] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
[332930.790552] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Preferred minimum I/O size 4096 bytes not a multiple of physical block size (0 bytes)
[332930.790556] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Optimal transfer size 33553920 bytes not a multiple of physical block size (0 bytes)
[332930.791424] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
                sda: rw=4096, sector=2, nr_sectors = 2 limit=0
[333074.300411] EXT4-fs (sda): unable to read superblock

Most of it didn't seem too helpful, besides maybe Volume was not properly unmounted. Some data may be corrupt. Please run fsck.
So I ran sudo fsck /dev/sda, and the answer I got was (roughly translated):
fsck.ext2: invalid argument when trying to open /dev/sda

The superblock couldn't be read, or did not contain a correct ext2/ext3/ext4 filesystem.
If the peripheral is valid and truly contains an ext2/3/4 FS (and not a swapfs, ufs, or other), 
then then superblock is corrupted, and you could try running e2fsck with another block :
    e2fsck -b 8193 <peripheral>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <peripheral>

At this point I feel reluctant trying my luck with some e2fsck commands. I hope the Nvidia support has a solution for that, but they haven't answered me yet and probably won't during weekends. I should precise -- when I replace the drives in the server, it boots normally, besides the fact that it shuts down extremely quickly. So I would like to try and avoid possibly FS-breaking solutions, as the data is still "technically" intact. I haven't tried to plug a bootable key to do the data transfers, since I assume the problem would be identical, but maybe I will.
I apologize for the lack of some details, the station was bought and used "as is", and Nvidia spins a lot of proprietary things in it that are extremely prone to breaking if you try to tweak them, so I didn't dig extremely deep into the station's exact configuration.
Thanks a bunch for your time !
Frost
Edit :
User @frostschutz suggested that I look a little more closely at the dmesg output, this is what I got when plugging in, if it is any help:
[397566.232752] usb 2-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[397566.246802] usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=152d, idProduct=0578, bcdDevice= 5.08
[397566.246818] usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[397566.246823] usb 2-2: Product: USB
[397566.246827] usb 2-2: Manufacturer: jmicron
[397566.246831] usb 2-2: SerialNumber: 0000000000080
[397566.249988] scsi host0: uas
[397566.250953] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     USB      3.0              0508 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[397566.254890] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[397572.213020] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Unit Not Ready
[397572.213036] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[397572.213047] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] ASC=0x44 <<vendor>>ASCQ=0x81 
[397572.214115] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Read Capacity(16) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[397572.214127] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[397572.214133] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] ASC=0x44 <<vendor>>ASCQ=0x81 
[397572.215017] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[397572.215027] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[397572.215033] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] ASC=0x44 <<vendor>>ASCQ=0x81 
[397572.215227] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 0 512-byte logical blocks: (0 B/0 B)
[397572.215231] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 0-byte physical blocks
[397572.215768] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Test WP failed, assume Write Enabled
[397572.215931] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Asking for cache data failed
[397572.215933] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
[397572.216484] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Preferred minimum I/O size 4096 bytes not a multiple of physical block size (0 bytes)
[397572.216488] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Optimal transfer size 33553920 bytes not a multiple of physical block size (0 bytes)
[397572.217257] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk


It's a hardware issue, the drive is not working. Are you using an adapter? Perhaps try another one?

Look at dmesg without using | grep, with grep you just miss things. If it's too much text use | tail -n 100 (to show the last e.g. 100 lines) or | less so you can scroll and search.

Yes, I am using several adapers, the drive is in SCSI, I use a SCSI ->SATA adapter, then one SATA->USB. I haven't been able to find a direct SCSI-> USB adapter, but I have confirmed the SATA->USB works with my SATA drives. I have ordered another SCSI adapter but it won't arrive before next week. For your comment on dmesg, good idea, I'll try and tell you if I can find anything

Adapters are often a bit wonky, chaining them together exacerbates such issues. I suppose the controller in your overheating machine is not an addon card or otherwise not reachable? If you share the make and model of your drive, perhaps someone would know a good way to connect it, or you could ask in a more hardware oriented forum.

I'd be careful of that chain of adapters; they're not reading the disk properly (all those "0 byte" size entries!).  It also confuses me that you initially saw 16Gb (is this correct?  Really?) before it said zero ("detected capacity change" line).
All those "unit not ready" messages make me wonder; is this a traditional spinning hard disk?  It might be that it's not get enough power to bring the platters up to speed!

@frostschutz I have added the dmesg output at the end of the question. The drive is a NVME SSD, Kioxia brand. The server's inside is filled with screwed-on plastic and metal, I doubt I can fetch the RAID card but I'll try
@StephenHarris Sorry I called it a drive out of habit but it's a SSD. Unfortunately there's barely anything useful written on the drive, not even the capacity, but it should be 1TB. I'm not too worried about the power delivery, as the data adapter is a 3.5" SATA reader that has a separated power supply to spin big hard drives - I'm not powering it with my small laptop.
